# Access SQL nesting inner joins

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to SQL and am trying to get my head around Access syntax as well as nesting queries.  My query is this: 
I am attempting to produce:  Employee first name, last name and employee id plus project number

I have tables

PROJECT

which has project_name that links to

JOB and project_Number

which also has Employee_id that links to

EMPLOYEE

so I wrote:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM (EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN JOB ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID=JOB.EMPLOYEE_ID) 
INNER JOIN PROJECT ON PROJECT.PROJ_NAME=JOB.PROJ_NAME
(SELECT PROJECT_NO
FROM PROJECT);
```

Comment: And describe the issues that you have with your query.

Comment: Can you include some sample data?  Just 3 or 4 records or something will do.  It's easier to visualize this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you're saying, this should work.  However, I'd guess that `project` and `job` are related based on `project_id` and not `project_name`.  Also, what the context of your question states (`project_name`) differs from your sample query (`proj_name`), so I'm going with your sample query.  If you show a schema, we can help better.

```
SELECT employee.FIRSTNAME, employee.LASTNAME, project.PROJECT_NO
FROM 
    (
        EMPLOYEE 
        INNER JOIN 
        JOB 
            ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = JOB.EMPLOYEE_ID
    )
    INNER JOIN 
    PROJECT 
        ON PROJECT.PROJ_NAME = JOB.PROJ_NAME
```

Comment: ahhh yep of course re the select line - thankyou.  I am getting missing operator tho on the joins

Comment: @user3296742 I have added the parentheses around one of the joins as required by Access SQL. Try it now.

Comment: Great, I have to get into work Ill have a look more tho as it hasnt populated

Comment: I think this is correct and there may be an issue with Access